# Using AJAX to append records?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In `index.html.erb`, I have an AJAX form:

```
<%= form_for @todo, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %> <%= f.text_field :name%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user, :value => current_user.email %>
  <%= f.submit "Add to todo list" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit things using it, I see them appear on my index page as it should be. However, I am now trying to make the latest added element appear instantaneously.

So I made `create.js.erb`

```
<% if @todo.valid? %>
    $(".todos").append('<li><%= @todo.name %></li>');
    console.log("in here");
<% else %> 
    // Flash message below!
    alert('Something went wrong!');
<% end %>
```

But for some reason, I am unable to see the record being added instantaneously? I never see either my `console.log` or `alert` message above meaning it never executes that code snippet. What's going on?

Also, this might be relevant, on form submit, I see: `GET http://localhost:3000/todos 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Here are the relevant routes

```
                root GET    /                              home#index
               todos GET    /todos(.:format)               todos#index
                     POST   /todos(.:format)               todos#create
            new_todo GET    /todos/new(.:format)           todos#new
           edit_todo GET    /todos/:id/edit(.:format)      todos#edit
                todo GET    /todos/:id(.:format)           todos#show
```

And in the controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @todo = Todo.new
        @todos = Todo.where(done:false)
    end
def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :done, :user)
end
def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.save
        redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Could you paste the `create` action?

Comment: @markets Sorry about that - I just did.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I don't really get redirected to an error - so I'm not sure how to bring that up. Or is that a log I should be able to generate that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your create method to the following:

```
def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @todo.save
            format.js
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end
end
```

Long story short: Your controller isn't being told to render javascript, so it's returning 'todos_path' - which doesn't have a route defined. If you tell it to render js, it'll look for methodname.js.erb by default. With the change above, it should properly return the javascript.

Comment: Noted. However, this still does not take care of the issue. 

Also, when I do a normal POST (not AJAX), I get this now: http://i.imgur.com/yySAUrQ.png

Comment: What does your server respond with when you make an AJAX POST? What do your server logs look like?

Comment: Just to clarify. When I did an AJAX submit, I only got `Error 500 Internal Server Error`. When I did a regular POST (not AJAX), I got the above pictured above. 

Here is the server log from that POST call http://ideone.com/gM9LoH

Comment: Makes sense - what do the server logs look like from the AJAX POST call?

Comment: Now it can't find the partial you're trying to render: it's looking for a file named '_todo.html.erb' in your views/todos directory. (Calling <%= j(render(@todo)) %> tries to render a partial). Remove that and replace it with something like <%= @todo.name %>, or create the appropriate partial file. Note that if you want to render a partial in JS like that, you'll need to do something like this: $(".blah").html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "/action_items/get_new") %>');

Comment: Perfect. I think the problem (strangely so) was that the commented line trying to render a partial was trying to be read. Thanks for walking me througoh that though - I learnt a lot about debugging Rails applications.

Comment: No problem! And yeah, while javascript was happily ignoring that line, Rails still recognized and was trying to render that rails tag. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 1):

Probable instance variable wrong name?

In `create.js.erb` file try with `<li><%= @todo.name %></li>` instead of `<li><%= @track.name %></li>`.

Another detail: in the permitted params (todo_params) I think you need to use `:user_id` instead of `:user`.

Also, you don't have to use a `redirect_to` after save the instance if you want to process the `js.erb` template, so your controller should send a `js` response for remote submits, something like (combined with html responses):

```
def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @todo.save
      format.html { redirect_to todos_path, notice: 'Your todo item was created!' }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to todos_path, notice: 'Something was wrong!' }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good eye on the typo - unfortunately that is not the cause of the problem. User is a column in my table, and the form fills it appropriately - so I'm not sure that is the problem either.